# Many-to-many Relationship Between Django Apps Fails

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-orm

**What's been done so far:**

- I was on Django 1.5 and upgraded to 1.6 (cannot go higher as we are on Python 2.6) and this did not solve the problem.
- I have researched this issue to death and cannot seem to find a definite answer. Looking through the Django Project Bug Tracker, I have seen similar issues but none seem to fit my particular case
- I have resolved the problem in the past using a raw SQL call to replace for example `affpart.damage_types.all()` with a custom function but this is starting to happen more frequently now and is becoming a real pain.

**Description:**

I have two Django apps under one project. One of the apps makes use of models in another app using a many-to-many relationship.

This has been working smoothly for months, and in fact it works fine on my production machine but fails on my development machine. The scenario lately has been that I am asked to add a new feature and when I start to work on it I get a `FieldError` in related code which I haven't even touched.

The offending line of code for this latest issue is:
`for dt in affpart.damage_types.all()`

The error is:

```
Cannot resolve keyword u'affectedpart' into field. Choices are: cgs_damage_code, description, id, reg_exp, sti
```

The error occurs in the bowels of Django in the `query.py` module.

From a high-level, this error occurs when I am trying to use a Many-to-many between models in different Django apps. For example, an affected part can have more than one type of damage and a damage type can be found on different affected parts.

The two apps are: `trending` and `sitar`

`sitar` was built first and has the models that I want to use from trending.

In `trending`, my `models.py` file has an `AffectedPart` model something like this:

```
from sitar.models import (Part, DamageType, Aircraft)

# this model is in trendin.models
class AffectedPart(models.Model):
    res = models.ForeignKey(Res, null=True)
    arising = models.ForeignKey(Arising, null=True)

    aircraft = models.ForeignKey(Aircraft)
    # filled out automatically only if part to Damage/Repair type matching done
    maintenance_phase = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                         choices=MAINTENANCE_PHASE_CHOICES)
    occurrence_date = models.DateField()
    partnumber = models.ForeignKey(Part)
    damage_types = models.ManyToManyField(DamageType, null=True, blank=True)
    repair_types = models.ManyToManyField(RepairType, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self, ):
        if self.res:
            parent = self.res.number

        else:
            parent = str(self.arising)

        return '{0} - {1}'.format(self.partnumber.number, parent)

# The following models are in sitar.models    
class Part(models.Model):
    ''' This model is used to create pick-lists so the user can associate
        one or more applicable parts from a pre-defined list to
        a tracked item.

        It will also allow for regular CRUD functionality which is
        implemented by taking advantage of the Django admin interface. '''

    # Added to associate a zone with a part
    zones = models.ManyToManyField("Zone", null=True, blank=True)

    number = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)
    material = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ''' Order by part number field (ascending) when presenting data '''
        ordering = ['number']


    def __unicode__(self):
        ''' Return unicode description of a part instance '''
        if self.description:
            return '%s -- %s' % (self.number, self.description)
        else:
            return self.number


    def get_encoded_part_number(self):
        '''
           This method will remove any '/' in part numbers and replace them
           with '~' so that they can be used in URLs.
        '''
        return self.number.replace('/','~')


class DamageType(models.Model):

    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    # a regular expression to account for possible spelling mistakes when
    # querying the database
    reg_exp = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    # Added to provide damage code for TRENDING
    cgs_damage_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True,
                                       verbose_name="CGS Damage Code")

    def __unicode__(self):
        ''' Return unicode representation of a DamageType instance. '''
        return self.description

    class Meta:
        ''' Order by description field (ascending) when presenting data '''
        ordering = ['description']

    def save(self):
        ''' Override the save method of the DamageType model in order to assign
            a regexp if one does not exist.'''

        # if the tracked item does not have a reg_exp just use
        # the description
        if not self.reg_exp:
            self.reg_exp = self.description

        super(DamageType,self).save()
```

Stack Trace

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/trending/trend/

Django Version: 1.6
Python Version: 2.6.7
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'sitar')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\cissimp\trending\views.py" in trend
  418.             list_result = utils.convert_queryset_to_lists(q_results, form)
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\cissimp\trending\utils.py" in convert_queryset_to_lists
  918.                            for dt in affpart.damage_types.all()]),
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in all
  133.         return self.get_queryset()
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in get_queryset
  539.                 return super(ManyRelatedManager, self).get_queryset().using(db)._next_is_sticky().filter(**self.core_filters)
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  590.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  608.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1198.         clause = self._add_q(where_part, used_aliases)
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1232.                     current_negated=current_negated)
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1100.                     allow_explicit_fk=True)
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in setup_joins
  1351.             names, opts, allow_many, allow_explicit_fk)
File "C:\virtual_env\sitar_env2\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in names_to_path
  1274.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /trending/trend/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword u'affectedpart' into field. Choices are: cgs_damage_code, description, id, reg_exp, sti
```

If anyone has a solution to this or knows of best practices for models in one application having many-to-many relationships with models in another application I would love to hear it.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the entire model class for both ```AffectedPart``` and ```DamageType```.

Comment: @schillingt -- I threw in Part as well.

Comment: What is the new feature you added that broke things?

Comment: One thing I can comment on is that instead of importing the models from the other app, you can do `damage_types = models.ManyToManyField('sitar.DamageType', null=True, blank=True)` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#lazy-relationships

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace? I don't think the offending line of code is generating the error you gave us. The reason is because it says ```affectedpart``` isn't a field, but I can't find ```affectedpart``` anywhere in the given code. Somewhere in a filter you're trying to use ```affectedpart``` and it doesn't exist on that model.

Comment: Can you add the definition of ```convert_queryset_to_lists``` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like somewhere you are trying to call:

```
damage_type.affectedpart.all()
```

Or something like that.
To get all the affected parts for your damage type you need to do something like:

```
damage_type.affectedpart_set.all()
```

You can read more about this in the [documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

If this is not your error please track the offending piece of code.

Comment: Thanks but that's not where the issue is.

Comment: What confuses me is that you say the offending line is affpart.damage_types.all() but the error resembles something like: damage_type.affectedpart.all() that is the exact oppossite

Comment: It makes as much sense to me as it does to you. I just followed the stack trace down. Line 918 starts the chain of events that leads to the error in the django.db.models.sql.query module

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the `DamageType` relationship from a `ForeignKey` to a `ManyToMany`?

I'm guessing you did and Django never created the intermediate table so it's trying to use the `DamageType` table. That's why it's looking for a relation to `AffectedPart`.

When you make model changes you should use something like [South](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for migrations since changing to a `ManyToMany` field is not quite as simple as it sounds.

Otherwise, create a ["through"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table on your own.

Comment: I have always have the relationship set up as it is from day one. Yes, I do use South. In the past I have used intermediary table but have not used "through" between applications. I'll give that a shot. Thanks.

Comment: I see, well I can't think of anything else atm. Maybe include the view that is used by `/trending/trend/` if that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

The error was occurring because I had neglected to put `"trending"` in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Since it was working in production with the exact same settings file, it never occurred to me to look there.

Thanks to Collin Anderson on django-users@googlegroups.com forum.

Some comments of interest by Collin:

1. How did you know!?!
   I hack... kidding :). I suspected something wasn't getting loaded, and the list of installed apps was in the traceback you posted.

2.I have the same code in production and it was working with no problems. Any idea why?
In development, most, if not all of your code is loaded and run on startup, and in production (at least before 1.7), things are really only loaded as needed. Basically with the app loading refactor and django.setup(), we're finally fixing problems like this.